# Condition guaranteeing integrability

Tags: stochastic-processes, characteristic-functions, levy-processes

Let us consider a Levy process $X_t$ with the characteristic function of the form:
$$
\hat{\mu}(t) = \text{exp}\biggl( i\gamma t - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} t^2 + \int_{\mathbb{R}} (e^{itx} - 1 - itx \mathbb{1}_{|x|\leq 1})\nu(dx) \biggr),
$$

where $(\gamma, \sigma, \nu)$ are parameters called the generating triplet.

It is well known-that we have to assume that
$$
\nu(\{0\}) = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}}(1 \wedge x^2)\nu(dx)<\infty
$$
These conditions guarantee that the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} (e^{itx} - 1 - itx \mathbb{1}_{|x|\leq 1})\nu(dx)$ is finite.

The indicator function occurring in the formula on characteristic function can be replaced by some function $c(x)$ and then:
$$
\hat{\mu}(t) = \text{exp}\biggl( i\gamma_c t - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} t^2 + \int_{\mathbb{R}} (e^{itx} - 1 - itx c(x))\nu(dx) \biggr),
$$
where
$$
\gamma_c = \gamma + \int_{\mathbb{R}} x (c(x) - \mathbb{1}_{|x|
\leq 1})\nu(dx)
$$

My question is:
What are necessary and sufficient conditions for $c(x)$?

I found in Sato's book titled 'Levy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions' that sufficient conditions are as follows:

$$
c(x) = 1 + o(|x|) \quad \text{as} \quad |x|\rightarrow 0 
$$
$$
c(x) = O\biggl(\frac{1}{|x|}\biggr) \quad \text{as} \quad |x|\rightarrow \infty
$$

However, I did not find anything about necessary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

In the formula on characteristic function of $X_1$, the Levy process $X=\{X_t,t\ge0\} $ at $t=1$,
\begin{align*}
 \hat{\mu}_1(u)&=\exp\Big(i\gamma u-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}u^2+\int_{\mathbb{R}}(e^{iux}-1-iux1_{\{|x|\le 1\}}) \nu(dx) \Big)\\
 &=\exp\Big(i\gamma_c u-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}u^2+\int_{\mathbb{R}}(e^{iux}-1-iuxc(x)) \nu(dx) \Big),
\end{align*}
since
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{\mathbb{R}}(1\wedge x^2)\nu(dx)<\infty, \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
to guarantee the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}(e^{iux}-1-iuxc(x)) \nu(dx)$ is finite for each $\nu$ satisfying (1), the necessary (and sufficient) conditions are
\begin{gather*}
 c(x)=O\Big(\frac{1}{|x|}\Big)\quad\text{as}\quad x\to\infty,\tag{2}\\
 c(x)=1+O(|x|), \quad\text{as}\quad\text{as}\quad x\to0.\tag{3}
\end{gather*}
On the other hand, in the discussion of weak convergence of IDDF (infinitively divisible distributions), the (2)(and (3)) are not sufficient(cf. Sato's book pp38 and pp41, Theorem 8.7), (2) and
\begin{gather*}
 c(x)=1+o(|x|), \quad\text{as}\quad\text{as}\quad x\to0.\tag{3}
\end{gather*}
are necessary.

Comment: I suppose that in formula (1) you mean $\int_{\mathbb{R}} (1\wedge x^2)\nu(dx)<\infty$

Comment: I have one question, I understand that assumption $\int_{\mathbb{R}} (1\wedge x^2)\nu(dx)<\infty$ guarantees that the integral characteristic exponent is finite. But why do we have to assume that $\nu(\{0\})=0$?

Comment: @MMM, Sorry, this is a new question, please write a new post to discuss.